Why each atom is given zero oxidation state for the coordinate bond?
How a coordinate bond can be formed by donor atom more electronegative than acceptor atom ? How electrons can go from the donor atom overcoming the nuclear force in this case?
And even if the coordinate bond is formed between donor atom (more electronegative than acceptor atom) and acceptor atom(less electronegative than donor atom), why the oxidation state of the atoms are 0 ? won't the donor atom(more E.N.) still attract the electrons towards itself and get partial negative charge ?


[OP] How a coordinate bond can be formed by donor atom more electronegative than acceptor atom ? How electrons can go from the donor atom overcoming the nuclear force in this case?

Electronegativity is a empirical value to predict the polarity of a bond. A more electronegative atom can form a bond with a less electronegative atom; the electron density will be skewed toward the more electronegative atom. Here is a simple example (with a bond we would not call coordinate):
$$\ce{OH-(aq) + H+(aq) -> H2O(l)}$$
Oxygen is more electronegative, yet the hydroxide binds to the hydrogen ion.
And here is the classic example of a coordinate bond (Lewis base reacts with Lewis acid):
$$\ce{H3N + BH3 -> H3NBH3}$$

[OP] And even if the coordinate bond is formed between donor atom (more electronegative than acceptor atom) and acceptor atom(less electronegative than donor atom), why the oxidation state of the atoms are 0 ? won't the donor atom(more E.N.) still attract the electrons towards itself and get partial negative charge ?

The oxidation states of the atoms are not 0. For water, oxygen has the oxidation state of -2 and hydrogen of +1. For $\ce{H3NBH3}$, the oxydation state of nitrogen is -3, of boron is +3, and of hydrogen is either +1 or -1, depending on the bonding partner. The oxidation states don't change as a lone pair of the more electronegative (oxygen or nitrogen) makes a covalent bond with the less electronegative one (hydrogen or boron).
Oxidation state is independent of partial charges. A third charge concept is that of formal charge. This does change in these two reactions, with oxygen changing from -1 to zero, nitrogen from zero to +1 and boron from zero to -1.

See also: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/128123
